# Angular $q promise Error: object is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a factory method which has $http(async task) so i used $q promise and the following error has occurred `TypeError: object is not a function` @line: return $q(funtion....)

written using **Promise API:**

```
service.fetch = function(query) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject){
        $http({ url: srcset[query], method: 'GET'}).success(function(db){
            resolve(db);
        });
    });
};
```

but if written with **Deferred API:**

```
service.fetch = function(query) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({ url: srcset[query], method: 'GET'}).success(function(db){
        deferred.resolve(db);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

It works fine

I have written exactly as mentioned in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Can anyone point out where have i gone wrong.

Comment: angular version discrepancy? https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/api/ng/service/$q is different

Comment: ok got it the documentation i referred to is 1.3 build 
but i was using 1.2.25. Thanks a lot, please post it as an answer many might have been making this mistake

Comment: added an answer for you so we can mark this as resolved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs you link to are the latest and may not be the correct version of angular.  Made that mistake before.

[1.2.25 (Stable) Docs for $q](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/api/ng/service/$q)